# Script for a list of data on STDIN returning most common values

Tags: perl

I'm trying to write a script that takes a list of data I.e brands on standard input and gives an output of the 10 most common bits of data including counts.

I'm planning on using PERL but please correct me otherwise

Comment: So, what is your question? What have you tried so far? You said you want counts – how would you count the pieces of data? Once we have a count, we can sort the data and select the top 10, no? All of this is quite basic. (PS: the language is called Perl. It is not an acronym.)

Comment: Thanks for the responseMy question is How do I do it? I am looking for some guidance on the matter. Let's forget about the counts for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne '
  $s{$_}++ 
}{ 
  print map "$s{$_}: $_",
   (sort {$s{$b} <=> $s{$a}} keys %s)[0..9]
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using common Linux commands:

```
sort <input file> | uniq -c | sort -g | tail -n 10
```

Explanation:

- `sort`: Sort the input data, either from a file or a pipe
- `uniq -c`: group the sorted data and count occurrences
- `sort -g`: sort the grouped/counted data numerically, ascending
- `tail -n 10`: take the last 10 results