# Perl Script only displaying first line of text file

Tags: perl

When I run this script, it only outputs the first line of my text file.

It is supposed to take a list of email addresses and output the ten most occurring domains.

For example, Timmy@yahoo.co.uk => 4
             Joebloggs@hotmail.com => 3

```
 #!D:\Perl\bin\perl

    #Read file
    open F, "<Emails.txt" or die $!;
    while (<F>) {
        print $_;
    {

    close F;

    perl ne 
      $s{$_}++ 
    }{ 
      print map "$s{$_}: $_",
       (sort {$s{$b} <=> $s{$a}} keys %s)[0..9] }}
```

Comment: Since you're using it, you should accept @mpapec 's answer to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250806/script-for-a-list-of-data-on-stdin-returning-most-common-values/18251158#18251158

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't this:

```
while (<F>) {
    print $_;
{

close F;
```

close your filehandle within your while() loop i.e. after your first line ? I suspect you need something like:

```
while(<F>) {
   # do something
}
close(F);
```

Answer (score 4):

what you are trying to do is like this which will close filehandle at the end of 1st while loop
hence you are getting first line only . hence you need to close it outside filehandle

```
open (FH ,'<',"text.txt") or die "can't open";
while(<FH>)
{      
    print $_;
    close FH;
}
```

try this:

```
open (FH ,'<',"text.txt") or die "can't open";

while(<FH>)
{      
    print $_;
}
close FH;
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to use @mpapec's answer to: [Script for a list of data on STDIN returning most common values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250806/script-for-a-list-of-data-on-stdin-returning-most-common-values)

You should pass the contents of `Emails.txt` into that command:

```
perl -ne '
  $s{$_}++ 
}{ 
  print map "$s{$_}: $_",
   (sort {$s{$b} <=> $s{$a}} keys %s)[0..9]
' Emails.txt
```

However, this answer doesn't cater for extracting the domain. To do that you'd need to replace the first line with:

```
$s{(split /@/)[1]}++
```